# I would want to know whether the below code is correct

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Is the below code correct .And if the autowiring is correct. Am in overlooking anything?

```
 @Component
    public class SampleBean {

    @Autowired
    private Bean1 b1;
    
    @Autowired
    private Bean2 b2;
    
    
    private String property;
    
    public SampleBean(Bean1 b1, Bean2 b2) {
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
    }
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be correct, depending on the rest of classes - however coming to StackOverflow without **specific** questions is more dangerous than assuming someone's gender in 21st century, in other words - buy a book on Spring and don't just ask to check your code